# Error message running php5-fpm

Tags: php, ubuntu

When trying to manually start php-fpm on ubuntu (12.04.2), got error:

```
#/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm: 37: /etc/init.d/php5-fpm: init_is_upstart: not found
```

my php5 is `Source: php5
Version: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you review this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464157/cant-start-or-stop-php-fpm-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks @chrisjlee.  It helps.  If you could "answer" the (albeit duplicate) question, I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a possible answer here:

> I see exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04, you can stop / start /
>   get status of php5-fpm using the service commands: I.E these work fine
>   :-
>
> sudo service php5-fpm status php5-fpm start/running, process 18793
>
> sudo service php5-fpm stop php5-fpm stop/waiting
>
> sudo service php5-fpm status php5-fpm stop/waiting
>
> sudo service php5-fpm start php5-fpm start/running, process 18949
>
> sudo service php5-fpm status php5-fpm start/running, process 18949
>
> BUT the /etc/init.d/php5-fpm command has no effect :-

Source: [Can't start or stop php-fpm on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464157/cant-start-or-stop-php-fpm-on-ubuntu)

Does that work?